# Jquery working on locahost but not on server (Web Applications with Master Pages)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-applications

Well I have a web Application with this code at HEAD tag on a Master Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"   src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-3.3.1.js")%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src='<%= ResolveClientUrl ("https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js") %>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src='<%= ResolveClientUrl ("https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js") %>'></script>    
 <script type="text/javascript"  src='<%= ResolveClientUrl ("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js") %>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src='<%= ResolveClientUrl ("http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore.js") %>'></script>
```

and if I Run it on localhost it works. But when I Publish the Web application on the server. This generates error "Jquery is not defined"
In the DataTables scripts, Jquery UI, and Bootstrap.

I used to place the code in a conventional way as if it were an HTML page. But on the internet I read that I could try it in that way that I placed before.

I hope you can support me.

Comment: Open up your developer tools and go to the network tab, then refresh the page.  You should see the network request in there for the jquery library.  Make sure it is getting a 200 or 304 response code.

Comment: Hi! Taplar, int the Network Tab appears 200 as a Response. In this case, what I should to do?